# How to configure named secondary interface on rhel or fedora

Tags: networking, redhat, fedora

I want to create a named interface file such that the output from ifconfig shows vlan10:HR or vlan10:Desks. I know how to create this in sales with

Ifcfg-vlan10

```
Ipaddr_0=x.x.x.x
Netmask_0=y.y.y.y
Label_0=HR
Ipaddr_1=z.z.z.z
Netmask_1=y.y.y.y
Label_1=Desks
```

My question is how do I accomplish the same in rhel or fedora?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can set names for interfaces by generating device names in udev rules, based on their MAC addresses.  It's a bit too involved to try and work out a scenario here for you, but it is well documented over at [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames)